# Tool to see nested permissions?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, file-permissions

Here's the situation. Often I need to tell how a user is getting access to a specific folder. I can see in "Effective permissions" that they have read/write/etc, but because of nested groups I can't immediately tell why.

I'd like a tool/script that I can run that will take the input of a path, and user and tell me how that user has permissions.

Example.

I'm on Server01 and I browse to c:\folder and I see that user MathewC has effective permissions to write, but when I look at the permissions for the folder, I can see that many groups have access to write, but I don't know which of those groups MathewC is a memeber of.

So, the permissions of the folder would look like this:

C:\folder

- Group 01 Read/Write
- Group 02 Read/Write
- Group 03 Read/Write
  ...
- Group 99 Read/Write

And the tool/script would report back

User MathewC is a memeber of "Group 42" which has Read/Write access.

Or even more complex:

User MathewC is a memeber of "Group humans" which is a member of "Group 42" which has Read/Write access.

Comment: Make sure and put the script up on poshcode.com and let us know once you're finished. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically this question (and this answer) are Off-Topic as "shopping" but I'll try and help you out.

You should be able to use Chris' NTFS Permissions Reporter to do what you need.  I've been using it for a while now.

[NTFS Permissions Reporter](http://cjwdev.co.uk/Software/NtfsReports/Info.html)

The free one can basically do what you are asking.

For instance, you can ask about a specific folder like: "\server01\share\folder\subfolder" and set the options as below:

[image]

Then after the report runs, you can click on one of the users in the results pane to see how they got their effective permissions and from what Group.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I word this question so it's not "shopping"?

Comment: I think you're fine here MathewC.  This wasn't the typical "Tell me which software to buy" question.